# Angular Material Checkbox doesn't represent the one-way binded value

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When using one-way data binding with a checkbox, the checkbox check mark doesn't represent the proper value of binded value. It can be checked and unchecked independently to the value.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is the code:

```
<mat-checkbox
    class="example-margin"
    (click)="onSelect(0)"
    [checked]="selected === 0">
</mat-checkbox>
<br>
<mat-checkbox
    class="example-margin"
    (click)="onSelect(1)"
    [checked]="selected === 1">
</mat-checkbox> 
<h1>selected: {{selected}}</h1>
```

```
    export class CheckboxConfigurableExample {
      checked = true;

      selected: number;

      onSelect(i: number) {
        this.selected = i;
      }
    }
```

Here is a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o636xe

Answer (score 0):

if you just add `$event` parameter and in the function call `event.preventDefault()` it will work normally.

if someone can explain this that would be great.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o636xe-wdjb31

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you can simply change `(click)` to `(change)`:

```
<mat-checkbox
    class="example-margin"
    (change)="onSelect(0)"
    [checked]="selected === 0">
</mat-checkbox>
<br>
<mat-checkbox
    class="example-margin"
    (change)="onSelect(1)"
    [checked]="selected === 1">
</mat-checkbox>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o636xe-xbvtjr)

Comment: Problem this way is, I can uncheck the box eventhough the value is still 1 (which it is supposed to)